# Find a file and copy it to a folder

Tags: shell, file, grep, find, zip

I'm doing a script that is intended to copy a file to another directory based on a given file path as input. Problem is that it copies the whole folder but the file I'm trying to copy. I tried different options and commands but the result is the same. I'll appreciate your help.

The file I'm trying to copy is "`12345.xml`"

**My code**

First, script looks for string `"may2017"` on a zip folder name. Displaying a list of zipped folder names that matches pattern, then it will look for the file `"12345"` on each folder list, so the final result will be only one matching zipped folder. Then, the desired result will be to copy the xml file.

`find "/path/SourceFolder" -name "*may2017*" -exec grep -l "12345" /dev/null {} + | xargs -I % cp % "/path/TargetFolder"`

This is the actual output when running the following commands ( `find "/path/SourceFolder" -name "*may2017*" -exec grep -l "12345" /dev/null {} +`):

**Actual Output**

`/path/SourceFolder/Folder_may2017`

**Desired Output**

`/path/SourceFolder/Folder_may2017/12345.xml`